# IE7 not support wysihtml5 editor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internet-explorer, wysihtml5

I'm using  wysihtml5 editor in my rails app . It works properly in all browser but not in IE < 8.
How can I use this editor on IE browser which are less than IE8(eg IE 7)?
I'm using gem 'bootstrap-wysihtml5-rails'.

Comment: Can i ask why you would support IE7? Its marketshare is very low (less than 1%) and declining: http://gs.statcounter.com/#browser_version_partially_combined-ww-monthly-201203-201302

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you take a look at the wysihtml5 github page, you'll find that it supports IE8+ (https://github.com/xing/wysihtml5#browser-support). So IE7 is not supported.

It will gracefully degrade, so IE7 and IE6 users can edit the plain HTML.

You could use an other editor that supports IE7, for example [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) ([Supports IE6+](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Users_Guide/Compatibility))